# Installed SSD as second drive, BootMGR is missing after Norton restore (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, bootmgr

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to solve the “Bootmgr is missing” problem on Windows 7 machine?](https://superuser.com/questions/151031/how-to-solve-the-bootmgr-is-missing-problem-on-windows-7-machine)

I've just bought a shiny SSD to add to my Dell Studio 1747 laptop. This has been installed as a second drive .

Since Dell don't ship their laptops with Windows 7 discs, a year ago when I bought the PC I used Norton Ghost 12 to create a recovery point. I have now restored that recovery point to the SSD and set it as Active.

When I restart the laptop, setting the SSD to primary boot drive, I get the message "BootMGR is missing". A google search and I find out that I am missing the 100MB "System Reserved" partition on the SSD to make it bootable.

How can I fix this? I've googled it and most solutions say to use the Windows 7 disc to re-intall or repair. I don't have this.

Alternatively I can use bcdboot.exe from the command line but how?

Current discs:

- C: Windows 7 (old installation, currently boots from here)
- F: SSD Drive with Windows 7 but missing BootMGR
- H: Secondary drive with files/folders

Comment: Funny how people clone a disk, but don't select the disk, but rather the partition.  I've seen this one too many times.

Comment: Newer versions of Norton are to blame. Too noddy. The old dos version that did a forensic clone worked wonders

Answer (score 0):

Solved by scrabbling around for a Win7 disc and just installing fresh. Once id done that I used the saved disc image to restore the C drive over the top. The result, I got my restored C and BootMGR.

A hassle but in the end the disc was needed.